# Bootstrap 3: Dropdown menu on a fix top bar navbar inverse NOT DROPPING DOWN

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

It seems that the code is fine but on browser the drop down menu does not work the menu is simply not dropping down... I have attached the js script string as well... I don't know what to do, I can't find the problem...

Thanks,

Max

```
<div class="row">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>MENU</button>  
</div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active" class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Home<span     class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Last Minute</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News Letter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>                    
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Africa<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Health</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Flights</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ferry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Train</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Overland</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Destinations<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">      
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Burundi<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bujumbura</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gorilla</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Safaris</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Kenya<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Nairobi</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mombasa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Safaris</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Rwanda<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Kigali</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gorilla</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"Safaris</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Tanzania<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dar es Salaam</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Arusha</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Safaris</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Kilimanjaro</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Zambia<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lusaka</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Zambezi River</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Safaris</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Zanzibar<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Stonetown</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Beach</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Festivals</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Serene<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Payments</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Members<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Rates<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                           <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data=toggle="dropdown">Burundi<span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                 <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                 <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                           <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Kenya<span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                 <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                 <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                           <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Rwanda<span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                           <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Tanzania<span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                           <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Zambia<span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                           <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Zanzibar<span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                         </ul>
                     </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">High Resolutions Pictures</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>             
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- javascript -->

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/dist/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="/dist/js/docs.min.js"></script>
  <script>$(function () {$('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show');});</script>
  <script>$('a.btn-info').tooltip()</script>
  <script>$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()</script>

<!-- End Body -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This works when I throw it into a sample rails 4 app with bootstrap-sass setup. Are you sure that your dropdown menu isn't opening? I had an issue with a previous app where I thought it wasn't opening, but it was just being hidden by the containing element which was accidentally set to 'overflow: hidden;'.

Either way, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted.